# Receiving two messages from .net core SignalR and react

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, websocket, signalr

I am trying to set up a WebSocket connection using the .net SignalR and React app as a client to be able to send private messages.

Here is my code on the client side:

```
const setUpSignalRConnection = async () => {
    const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://localhost:5000/messaginghub")
      .build();

    setConnection(connection);

    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message: string) => {
      console.log("Recieved Message", message);

      setChatMessages((oldArray) => [...oldArray, message]);
    });

    try {
      await connection.start();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Errors", err);
    }

    return connection;
  };


  const SendMessage = async () => {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        console.log("sending message");
        await connection.send("SendPrivateMessage", user.user.email, message);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("Errors sending message", e);
      }
    } else {
      alert("No connection to server yet.");
    }
  };
```

and my server side code

```
       public async Task SendPrivateMessage(string userEmail, string message)
        {
            var RecivingMessageUser = _unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetByEmail(userEmail);

            var currUserEmail = Context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            var sender = _unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetByEmail(currUserEmail);

            var newMessage = new MessagesDto
            {
                FromId = sender.UserId,
                ToId = RecivingMessageUser.UserId,
                MessageBody = message,
                SentAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
            };

            await Clients.Group(userEmail).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);

            _unitOfWork.MessagingRepository.Insert(_mapper.Map<MessagesDto, Messages>(newMessage));
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var groupName = Context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception ex)
        {
            Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));

            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(ex);
        }
```

With console.logs I see that I am sending a message once and the message is stored in DB once but somehow on the other end, I am getting two received messages.

I am testing it on my local machine in two separate browsers.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Which method on your back-end is calling twice?
You are telling  your message saved in to the DB once so it shouldn't be the `SendPrivateMessage` method which is calling towice.

Comment: Hey sorry, it was pretty urgent. I couldn't make it work so I went for something else.
Nevertheless, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal problem with SignalR response with client side application because our response not waiting for the server, so try add the setTimeout(() => setChatMessages((oldArray) => [...oldArray, message]), 1); and i hope you will get what you want.